# Is locally lipschitz the power function?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, lipschitz-functions

**Definition:(Hale,1980)** A function $f(x)$ defined in a domain $D$ in $R^{n}$ is said to be *locally Lipschitzian* in $x$ if for any closed bounded set $U$ in $D$ there is a $k=k_{U}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|$ for $x, y$ in $U$.

(I need work with this definition.)

With above definition, is the function $f(x,y)=xy^c$, $0\leq x,y$ and $c=\frac{a}{b},$ with $a,b$ positive integers, *locally Lipschitzian* ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the boundary of the domain. Recall that every $C^1$ function is locally lipschitz (by the MVT), and note that $f$ is $C^1$ in $x,y >0$.

Comment: The problematic part is the part $\{ (x,0) : x \geqslant 0\}$ of the boundary. It depends on the value of $c$, $f$ is locally Lipschitz if and only if $c \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Is true. The boundary is a problem. If  $$a < b$$ I proved that function is not LL. If $$b \leqslant  a$$ the function is LL. Thanks @Crostul.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're right. $$1 \leqslant c $$  . I have a question: If c is a real number, is f derivable in y?

Comment: Whether $c$ is rational or irrational doesn't matter. For $y > 0$, the function is smooth, whatever value $c$ has. On the line $\{y = 0\}$, we have differentiability if and only if $c \geqslant 1$.

Comment: I will consider $c \geqslant 1$ and c a real number in my thesis. Thanks @DanielFischer.